# web setup project - Place web app in IIS default website not virtual directory

Tags: iis-6, setup-deployment, web-setup-project

I am creating a web setup project using .net 2010. the setup is build successfuly. but when i install the setup it install the web site in virtual directory.

like this

[image]

Now i want Place web app in IIS default website not virtual directory or enable site textbox for entry.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just leave the Virtual Directory blank and it'll install directly into the root of the site (confirmed with VS2010).